# Issues Drawing Certain Features From ArcGIS FeatureLayers Using html2canvas

Tags: leaflet, arcgis, html2canvas

We are using Leaflet in conjunction with plug-ins for Here Maps, WMS and ESRI.  We are using html2canvas to convert the map view to an image to allow users to sketch on it.  This has been working without issues for Here, WMS and ArcGIS Enterprise/service layers.  We recently updated the mapping to implement ArcGIS Online/feature layers with the inclusion of the esri-leaflet-renderers plug-in.  We've noticed that with the features layers, if they are an image and have base64 data in the JSON response from ESRI, they will draw when converting to an image, but anything that doesn't have base64 in the response (lines, polygons, etc.) will not draw.  I was able to find the ESRI screenshot-widget which might be of use, but we are not using ArcGIS API for JavaScript.  Does anyone know of a way to accomplish drawing all features in the generated image with what we are using today?